# Locating a website element using selenium webdriver for automation task

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am working on a project using selenium webdriver which requires me to locate an element and click on it. The program starts by entering a website , clicking the searchbar , typing in a preentered string and clicking enter , up to this point everything is successful. The next thing I want it to do is find the first result of the search and click on it. This part I am having trouble with. I have successfully located all elements up to this point but i cant locate this one as an error pops up. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

trackname = input("Track Name: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://music.apple.com/us/artist/search/166949667')

time.sleep(2)

searchbox = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
searchbox.send_keys(trackname)
from keyboard import press
press('enter')
time.sleep(2)

result = driver.find_element_by_id('search-list-lockup__description')
result.click()
```

I have tried locating the element other ways but it wont work , I am guessing that the issue is that after searching I have to tell it to search on that page but I am not sure. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projekti\iTunesDataFiller\iTunesDataFiller.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = driver.find_element_by_id('search-list-lockup__description')
  File "D:\Python App\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "D:\Python App\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "D:\Python App\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python App\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="search-list-lockup__description"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to the element you want to access not being available.
For example say you load the page, the element could not be visible to selenium. So basically you're trying to click on an invisible element.
I suggest using this template to make sure elements are loaded before accessing them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
waitshort = WebDriverWait(driver,.5)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
waitLonger = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
visible = EC.visibility_of_element_located
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path')
driver.get('link')
element_you_want_to_access = wait.until(visible((By.XPATH,'xpath')))
```